# passport.authenticate is not working at all

Tags: passport.js, koa, passport-facebook, koa2

I am trying to make social login in KOA2 using passport. When I try to authenticate the user with the help of passport.authenticate(). It is supposed to be executed and should throw me to the fb login page, but is is not doing so. Even it is showing Not Found and not throwing any kind of error. Here is my code sample:

app.js

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import views from 'koa-views'
import serve from 'koa-static'
import rootRoutes from './routes/index'
import userRoutes from './routes/user'
import authConfig from './config/oauth'
import authRoutes from './routes/social'
const app = new Koa()
// trust proxy
app.proxy = true

// sessions
const convert = require('koa-convert')
const session = require('koa-generic-session')
const passport = require('koa-passport')
app.keys = ['your-session-secret']
// body parser
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
// require('./auth')
app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(convert(session()))

// authentication
app.use(convert(passport.initialize()))
app.use(convert(passport.session()))
app.use(views(`${__dirname}/views`, { extension: 'html' }))
app.use(serve(`${__dirname}/public`))
app.use(authRoutes.routes())
app.use(authRoutes.allowedMethods())
app.use(rootRoutes.routes())
console.log("authRoutes", authRoutes);
app.use(rootRoutes.allowedMethods())
app.use(userRoutes.routes())
app.use(userRoutes.allowedMethods())
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next(); // next is now a function, await instead of yield
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.body = { message: err.message };
    ctx.status = err.status || 500;
  }
});
app.listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Server running at http://localhost:1337 and http://127.0.0.1:1337')
})

export default app
```

social.js

```
import Router from 'koa-router'
const router = new Router()
import authConfig from '../config/oauth'
import passport from 'koa-passport'
var user = { id: 1, username: 'test' }

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log(user)
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      // const user = await User.findById(id);
      console.log("user", user);
      done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error")
      done(error);
    }
  })();
});

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  console.log("user", user);
  // retrieve user ...
  if (username === 'test' && password === 'test') {
    done(null, user)
  } else {
    done(null, false)
  }
}))

var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: '214873665615110',
    clientSecret: 'f30ba1c22c6fef150c4b8ffae3cbffe4',
    callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:1337/auth/facebook/callback'
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    console.log("profile", profile);
    // retrieve user ...
    done(null, user)
  }
))

var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: 'authConfig.twitter.consumerKey',
    consumerSecret: 'authConfig.twitter.consumerSecret',
    callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:' + (process.env.PORT || 1337) + '/auth/twitter/callback'
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    // retrieve user ...
    done(null, user)
  }
))

var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-auth').Strategy
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientId: 'authConfig.google.clientID',
    clientSecret: 'authConfig.google.clientSecret',
    callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:' + (process.env.PORT || 1337) + '/auth/google/callback'
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    // retrieve user ...
    done(null, user)
  }
))

// import authConfig from '../config/oauth'
router.post('/login', async(ctx, next) => {
  console.log("login");
  await passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/about',
    failureRedirect: '/'
  })
  return next();
})

router.get('/auth/facebook', async(ctx, next) => {
    console.log("call aayi");
    await passport.authenticate('facebook');
    // ctx.body = "aa gaya bhai ";
})

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', async(ctx, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect: '/about',
        failureRedirect: '/'
    })
})
export default router
```

`oath.js` is having the credentials for the social plugins.

The interesting issue is, when I am using `koa-route` instead of `koa-router`. It's working.

```
const route = require('koa-route');
app.use(route.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook')
))

app.use(route.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: '/app',
    failureRedirect: '/'
  })
))
```

Everything remaining the same, just used `koa-route` for these two routes and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oww gosh, after so much of finding, got the answer.
The issue was with the dependencies.
koa-passport was to be installed with @next tag ie `npm install koa-passport@next` instead of `npm install koa-passport@latest`

Answer (score 0):

First thing I can see is that you are not serializing your user in and out of the session properly. Try serializing the user._id to the session that will later be used to retrieve a whole user from the database.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
done(err, user);
});
```

Comment: BTW same work in express, then how can this create any issue in koa? The thing is, we should store the least data is session, that's why we use user.id